# MySQL container crash after /etc/mysql/my.cnf change, how to edit back?

Tags: mysql, docker, crash, debian, containers

I changed some mysql config settings and set something wrong, now Docker container keeps restarting and I cannot find the `my.cnf` file to edit in host filesystem. I have tried aufs/diff folders but so far unable to find it. Also tried:

```
find / -name my.cnf -exec nano {} \;
```

But it does not bring up the file I changed. And I tried to change `config.v2.json` to start `/bin/bash` instead of `mysqld` and restarted docker, but yet it started `mysqld` (due supervisor or something?) using official mysql container image.

Comment: post the Dockerfile, the `docker run`command, any details helping, and you will need to build a new image

Comment: I am using **docker run --restart=always --log-opt max-size=10m --log-opt max-file=10 --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -d mysql** so not using dockerfile.

Comment: your mysql image comes from where? When you modified it, how did you do? just `docker exec` and then `docker commit`? Can you post `docker images | grep mysql`

Comment: _mysql                                          latest              7666f75adb6b        13 days ago         406 MB
_

Comment: From docker hub. I modified it using docker exec -it mysql bash, then edited /etc/mysql/my.cnf with nano, saved. Exited container and used **docker restart mysql** then it did not start because config was invalid.

Comment: See `docker commit` the doc is here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

Comment: Created new image from that old mysql container and run'd it, still unable to edit my.cnf file in host file system, new keeps restarting too since it has same config. I guess I'll try making volume of /etc/mysql folder next.

Comment: just launch your mysql image with a shell, such as `docker run ... my_mysql bash` and then you have a shell inside, you can debug. You should definitely have a Dockerfile, the idea behind docker is that is is easy and fast to get a new, updated, image

Comment: When I created volume, I can find that **my.cnf** but it seems to be symbolic link *my.cnf -> /etc/alternatives/my.cnf* so it appeas empty when editing. So only hope is to try and start container without mysqld starting somehow I guess?

Comment: I could link my own my.cnf to this mysql container with volume, which could avoid this issue, I have used docker for 1,5 years and always used databases without creating my own dockerfile/committing and running in production also. I guess its first time since I messed up with config since did not run into this issue before. Thought that this should be 5 minute thing to fix thou.

Comment: I run **docker run --restart=always --log-opt max-size=10m --log-opt max-file=10 --name mysql2 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -d mysql-committed bash** but it still keeps restarting and can't get to it. And **docker logs mysql-committed** gives empty result

Comment: check `docker events` the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/

Comment: you have several Dockerfile for Mysql at https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/, you can have a Dockerfile as short as `FROM mysql:latest` or `FROM mysql:5.6` and some specific configuration, with a `COPY`or `ADD` of some config file

Comment: I was able to get into config file, when I added -it to run command with bash and removed -d.. but after editing config I commited this "fixed" image and tried to run it and that doesn't work. It did not start mysqld and when i tried to start it manually it seems to start in fresh mode "No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started.".

Comment: I have used that page for run commands, thou did not check config part. It says to **docker run --name some-mysql -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag** use that conf.d folder for custom configs. So I have been doing it wrong then. And seems there is no simple way to fix it. At least this did not happen in production. I guess I use that conf.d folder. Still hesistant to make own Dockerfiles for databases since they are very similar and there doesn't seem to be need to.

Comment: To get rid of the restarting, you can issue `docker update --restart no <container_name>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing two possible solutions for your problem:

**Bypass the ENTRYPOINT for the MySQL image**

Find your image name by running `docker images` then run:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint="/bin/sh" OPTIONS image
```

That should take you to the bash inside the container and from there you can execute all the commands you want to find your `my.cnf` file. Although I don't know if editing the file from there, save it and try to run it again will works. I didn't tried.

**Delete the old image and use the proper way to edit the `my.cnf` file**

Find your image name by running: `docker images` and then delete it by running `docker rmi <image_name>`

Check the docs for the default MySQL images at [MySQL Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) is pretty straight on this and I quote:

> Using a custom MySQL configuration file The MySQL startup
>
> configuration is specified in the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf, and that
>   file in turn includes any files found in the /etc/mysql/conf.d
>   directory that end with .cnf. Settings in files in this directory will
>   augment and/or override settings in /etc/mysql/my.cnf. If you want to
>   use a customized MySQL configuration, you can create your alternative
>   configuration file in a directory on the host machine and then mount
>   that directory location as /etc/mysql/conf.d inside the mysql
>   container.
>
> If /my/custom/config-file.cnf is the path and name of your custom
>   configuration file, you can start your mysql container like this (note
>   that only the directory path of the custom config file is used in this
>   command):
>
> `$ docker run --name some-mysql -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e
>   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag`
>
> This will start a new
>   container some-mysql where the MySQL instance uses the combined
>   startup settings from /etc/mysql/my.cnf and
>   /etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf, with settings from the latter
>   taking precedence.

From that point and if you create the `my.cnf` file on your host then you'll never run into this problem again since you can edit the file as many times as you want.

Comment: I came to same conclusion that I was editing configs wrong way. Above method does not really help on getting databases back which were lost due mysql not starting. Maybe they could be salvaged since they are on volume I think but thats job for another day when there is a real need for it.